# What is the name of $\hat{K}=\{x:\langle x,y\rangle \leq a \;\forall y\in K\}$ for $K$ convex subset of a Hilbert space?

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, terminology, convex-optimization

Suppose I have a convex set $K\subset X$, where $X$ is say a real Hilbert space (for simplicity). Then, given some $a\in \Bbb{R}$, let

$$
\hat{K}=\{x:\langle x,y\rangle \leq a \;\forall y\in K\}
$$

This is seemingly very similar to the idea of a polar set or polar cone, but I can't quite find a definition of this exact object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a very similar reference: The German "Funktionalanalysis" (functional analysis) by D. Werner: He defines for a (complex) locally convex topological vector space $X$ with dual $X'$:
$$A^\circ = \{ x' \in X' : \Re \langle x' , x\rangle \le 1 \; \quad\forall x \in A\}.$$
(In the real case, you can simply drop the "$\Re$".) He calls this set "Polare", I would translate this as "polar set". Note that if $A$ is a cone, this is indeed the polar cone.

Note that you can pull out the $a$ in your definition.
Indeed, we have
$$\hat K = a \, K^\circ.$$

Comment: For an English language reference, see Rockafeller's _Convex Analysis_, Section 14. As gerw noted, $a$ can be pulled out of the definition. And in the case where $K$ is a cone, by rescaling $y$ you have that necessarily $\langle x,y\rangle \leq \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}_\pm$, the sign depending on the sign of $a$. The positive sign gives you that $\langle x,y,\rangle \leq 0$ (the polar cone) and the negative sign gives the empty set.

Comment: I knew it had to be in Rockefeller somewhere, I guess I didn't look hard enough! Thanks!